# Introduction to newforms and oldforms

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

Looking for an introductory text on newforms and oldforms. I have only found http://sage.math.washington.edu/edu/Fall2003/252/lectures/11-12-03/11-12-03.pdf which is not introductory in nature.

Thanks

Comment: Try Iwaniec's book (I think it's called Topics in Automorphic Forms), or Diamond and Shurman (A First Course in Modular Forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find Diamond and Shurman to be the best first introduction to modular forms, including discussion of oldforms and newforms. I also find that Goldfeld's Automorphic L-Functions for GLnR (as opposed to his automorphic representation books) to be the best higher-level introduction.

The relationship between these is somewhat similar to the relationship between Atiyah-MacDonald and Eisenbud towards algebraic geometry: there's a lot of overlap, but Goldfeld is pitched much higher.